# Chrome is not working in Linux Mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint 19 Tara on my PC. I'm facing problems in running Chrome and installing updates on a LAN network. Other web browsers such as Firefox are working fine, and Chrome is running OK when the PC is connected to a Wi-Fi network.